# showing this -__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given- insted of search results

Tags: python

i am trying to search users and list view the search results in a file called userList.html
 views.py is as follows

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'userList.html'
    object_list = User.objects.all().exclude(username='monkey')

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            q = request.GET.get('q')
        except:
            q = None
            if name:
                object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains = name )).exclude(username='monkey')
                context = {
                'query': q, 'object_list':object_list
                }
                template = 'users/userList.html'
            else:
                context = {}  
                template = 'blog/home.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
```

error:

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner response = get_response(request) File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

expected search results

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error message. It is not clear which `__init__` the error message refers to.

Comment: You have no idea what are you doing ! You are trying to override `get_queryset()` method, it should return `QuerySet` object instance. Please, read `ListView` documentation carefully.

Comment: here is the trace back

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\code\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Please update the *question* with the traceback.

Comment: i have already tried to use the code in the documentation but its still giving errorclass SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'userList.html'
    model = User

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            name = self.request.GET.get('q')
        except:
            name = ''
        if (name != ''):

            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains = name )).exclude(username='monkey')
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all().exclude(username='monkey')
        return object_list